# Creating a list of objects error?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to create a list / array of objects. However, I am running into the following error and can't seem to figure out how to resolve it.

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the code that the error is pointing to:

```
# Create list of servers
for x in range(server_number):
    server_object = Server(x)
    servers.append(server_object)
```

Is this the right approach to creating a list of objects? If not what do you guys recommend?

Comment: Did you assign something to `range` or `Server` before these lines?

Comment: Always post the full traceback, not just the last line-- that way we can point the finger at the right culprit.

Comment: Do you have `import range` anywhere? or is tehre a module named `Server` you imported? Or is `servers` a module with a `append` module contained in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means, what *Server* is python module and not class. Check what you have do imports right.